# Return false in onEditorAction

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

The `TextView`'s `onEditorAction` method's documentation says

> Return true if you have consumed the action, else false.

Most examples I see online return true. But in this case, the soft keyboard stays opened.
Is it legit to return false to let the system handle the soft keyboard or does that have any side effects?

```
private TextView.OnEditorActionListener inputListener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (actionId) {
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's totally **OK**.

The documentation refers to the action you want to make, if you succeeded in your action, return `true`. `false` otherwise.

So.. the keyboard doesn't matter here. if you have problem with the keyboard just hide it yourself.

```
// Check if no view has focus:
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there any downside in letting the system handle the keyboard by returning false even tho I handled the click?

Comment: Not. at least from my experience and little research. does it work as supposed to be in your app? if it does, no worries.